# Get current user's user group in SPFx WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

How can I get the sharepoint groups the current user is a part/ belogns to, without `@pnp/sp` js framework in SPFx ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `spHttpClient` built-in with SPFx.

The endpoint you need to consume is `/_api/web/currentuser/groups`.

Add the below import statement:

```
import { SPHttpClient } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
```

After that you can add the below code:

```
    const queryUrl = `${this.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/currentuser/groups`;
    const siteGroupsData = await this.context.spHttpClient.get(queryUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1);
    const siteGroups = (await siteGroupsData.json()).value;
    siteGroups.forEach((siteGroup) => console.log(siteGroup));
```

Comment: getting error in "context"

Comment: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: i wrote this method inside the render method of `<webpartname>.ts` file

Comment: I wrote it there only.

Comment: public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactGetItemsProps> {

Comment: looks like you wrote this inside the react component file `.tsx`, i have written it in the `.ts` file's render method

Comment: 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.ts(1308)

Comment: you can modify it as `public async render() { ...` and then write the above code inside it

Comment: void gives error now. I'm new to SPFx. Sorry

Comment: Get rid of the void i.e `public render() { ... }`

Comment: thank you so much..It's working

Comment: Hi Gautam, I want use this usergroup value in tsx file. If assign it to a property in ts file, it's shows undefined in ts. Please advise.

Comment: Can you please ask that as a separate question ? Impossible to answer that in comments here :(

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import the library

```
import { CurrentUser } from '@pnp/sp/src/siteusers';
```

Then call the function to get the data

```
private getSPUserData(): void {      
  sp.web.currentUser.get().then((r: CurrentUser) => {  
    this.renderData(r['Title']);  
  });  
}
```

Where "r" is the SPUser Object, from this you can get

- Email
- LoginName
- Title (Name)

Then you can user this query to ask fro the user groups

```
private getSPUserGroup(): void {      
  sp.web.currentUser.groups.get().then((r: any) => {  
    let grpNames: string ="";  
    r.forEach((grp: SiteGroup) =>{  
      grpNames += "<li>"+grp["Title"]+"</li>"  
    });      
    grpNames = "<ul>"+grpNames+"</ul>";  
    this.renderData(grpNames);  
  });  
}
```

Hope it can help you.
Sya

Comment: This does not answer the question.  OP specifically asks how to get a user's Group and to do so without the use of pnp.

Comment: you're right i didn't read the group part, my apologies